# Storage explorer is not listing Cosmos DB documents

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage-explorer

I am using Azure storage explorer 1.11.2(version) and connect to my azure account. I am able to see blob storage however when I am trying to list down the cosmos DB documents then it is not listing anything. screenshot for your reference. It is not showing any error.
[image: Message in Azure storage explorer]

Please suggest on this.

Comment: It looks like an issue with the application. Please open an issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues.

Comment: It seems it's related to ms product issue,not coding issue.You can't get timely answer here,please follow @GauravMantri suggestion to open cases on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer version of Storage explorer deprecate the cosmos DB documents view, For that we need to use separate `Cosmos DB explorer`.

[image]

Comment: can you run update/delete command from this tool?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to upgrade to latest version [1.12.0](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/releases/tag/v1.12.0)(scroll to the end of the page, then select the file to download). It works well at latest version 1.12.0, screenshot as below:

[image]

If you persist using the old version, then post an issue as suggested in the comment.

Comment: no luck on that version also. 1.12.0 also causing me the same problem.